# SQL Query to Check presence of a Column of one table and a Column of another table as pair on a third table?

Tags: oracle, inner-join, cartesian-product

[image: Table structure]

1. Table1.col1 contains some Names and Table2.col2 is a datetime field.
2. Table 3 has both the two columns.
3. I'm using Oracle database.
4. Table3 is the master table which has more than a billion records.
5. Table1 and Table2 has no relation/link.

Expected output from above image:

**I need a query to fetch all those pairs of table1.column1 and table.column2 which are not present in Table3 against the respective columns Col1 and Col2. Any Logic or an approach will be helpful.**

Edit - The question is complete in itself because it's only looking for a logic or a pseudocode from the provided data.

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_, all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].

Comment: What's your dbms? `mysql <> oracle`

Comment: You've tagged this question for two different databases- Oracle and MySQL.  Which one are you actually using (different databases often support different dialects of SQL)?

Comment: How are the tables joined?

Comment: table 1 and table2 are not joined. Those are unique colmuns.
Table 1 column has some Name and Table2 Column2 is a datetime field.
Table 3 has both Name and DateTime field which needs to be compared as a pair.

Comment: @JustinCave- Its an Oracle DB. I've removed MYSQL DB. And that doesnt matters also. I'm only looking for a logic not even the exact query.
Any logic or an approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reproducible example would help.

My guess from your description is that you want to create a Cartesian product of `table1` and `table2` and `minus` `table3` from that Cartesian product

```
select t3.column1, t3.column2
  from table3 t3
minus
select t1.column1, t2.column2
  from table1 t1
       cross join table2 t2
```

If that is not what you are looking for, providing the reproducible example would be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes this is somewhat I was looking. Atleast you showed me an approach. Now by 'minus' I hope you mean difference set operation. As per  project requirements set operations are prohibited in our environment as we have billion records as it will be much expensive. Can we just sort this last thing by finding an alternative for 'minus'. It will be enough for me to write final query then.

Comment: @BriteRoy - Yes, `minus` is a set operation.  That's going to be the fastest way to find the difference between two sets.  You could certainly write your own `minus` operation in PL/SQL.  It'll just be vastly slower.

Comment: Okay great. I will try to write the query with minus operation and test it in my environment. Will share the results soon in a day. Thank you one again. For now I've accepted this answer 

Comment: Update - The query works absolutely fine and it takes around 4-5 minutes which is acceptable. Thanks a lot again for the logic approach. We can officially close the thread now.

Comment: @For the moderators who closed this question because of 'incomplete information' please have a look on above answer. Justin gave this answer with the same available information.